# Product management System Tracking with Google Tag Manager

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working on Product Management system site in which on the enquiry of a product i fill a contact us form which has the info of that product as follows 
[image]

as soon as the form is submitted it leads me on the thank you page where I have added the following code in order to track it using GTM

```
<?php
$enquiry_id = "";
$enquiry_id = $this->session->userdata('enq_id');
$product_data = "";
$product_data = $this->session->userdata('enq');
echo "<!--<pre>";
print_r($product_data);
echo "<pre>-->";
if (!empty($product_data) && !empty($enquiry_id) && isset($product_data)){
    ?>

<script>
 <?php
    foreach($product_data as $value){
    ?>
dataLayer.push({
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '<?php echo $enquiry_id?>'                      // Transaction ID. 

      },
      'products': [{                           
        'name': '<?php echo $value ?>',     
        'id': '<?php echo $enquiry_id?>',
        'price': '0.0',      
        'quantity': 1

       }]
    }
  }
}); 

<?php } ?>

</script>



<?php
$this->session->unset_userdata('enq_id');
$this->session->unset_userdata('enq');
}
?>
<script>
```

Now the thing is I am able to get the values in the GTM debugger as well as i can see them in view source but the values dont show up in Google Analytics , So is there any other way to get the values in the Conversion->Ecommerce section of GA.I have set the track type as Transaction in GTM.
Thanking you in advance

Comment: could u plz tell where are you setting GTM values in php code ?